# Game developer's logo isn't working.

Tags: bug, status-completed, logo

See here:

http://stackmobile.com/ *- towards the bottom*

Neither the main logo, nor the meta logo is workin.

Comment: Main logo is working for me.

Comment: @jjn: Hmmm... ya. Now just the Meta logo is not working.

Comment: Just to be clear, George is correct.  Goofy things are happening with logos right now.  -1s unwarranted etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This is *sort of* working, but be aware that a not insignificant refactoring of how we host images for SE sites is ongoing*.</strike>

We're trying to avoid any outages, but...

Also, if you're caching images without *ever* checking StackAuth for updates you'll probably want to fix that in the near future.

I'll update once we're done.

Looks like we're good to go.

<sub>*Not something I'm doing, so I can't make strong promises on how it'll end up</sub>

Comment: Don't worry, I don't cache anything longer than 15 min.